# Wrap More Link in Div

Tags: read-more

I would like to put the "more" link in it's own div and am having some trouble... my current code looks like:
    `the_content("<div class='more'>More &gt;&gt;</div>");`

But the problem is that the output is not cross-browser compatible...Safari and Firefox render this fine, placing the `div` around the more link...but IE8 renders the `div` in the `a` tag of the link, making it look funny.

Is there a function I can add to my theme that would allow me to wrap a `div` around the more link so I don't have to worry about how different browsers interpret my original code?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution on the WordPress forums, if anyone is trying to do the same thing here is the solution: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-read-more-text-wrapped-in-a-div

I added the following to my functions file:

```
function wrap_readmore($more_link) {
    return '<div class="post-readmore">'.$more_link.'</div>';
}
add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'wrap_readmore', 10, 1);
```

Thanks,
Josh